# PCA graph: Formal analysis of how each loading effects individual players?

Tags: pca, inference, redundancy-analysis

Here is a PCA example, with environment variables loaded in blue, species in red, and sites in black. I am trying to make two specific interpretations. I want to know if they are right and if there is a formal way of analyzing them further.

[image]

1. Species `GAR` and `ABL` lie further along the `dbo` gradient than`CHE`. Therefore, variability in`CHE` is explained more by `dbo` than the other two.
   **Q: Is there a formal way of looking at the distance of CHE, GAR and ABL from dbo?**
2. `Alt` loads most heavily on RDA 1. Therefore, Alt explains the most variation in the community matrix. But because it loads opposite to where most species and site are located, it is **negatively associated** with species abundances? **Is that correct?** How do I formally report this in my analysis?